# Scala Slick joinLeft and combined conditions

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I want to be able to create a query with `Slick` that let me filter left joins in a dynamic way

```
case class Player(
  id: Long,
  createdAt: DateTime,
  lastModificationDate: DateTime,
  name: String
)

class PlayerTable(tag: Tag)  extends Table[Player](tag, "players") {
  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def createdAt = column[DateTime]("createdAt")
  def lastModificationDate = column[DateTime]("lastModificationDate")
  def name = column[String]("name")
  override def * : ProvenShape[Player] = (
  id,
  createdAt,
  lastModificationDate,
  updatedAt,
  name
  ) <> (Player.tupled, Player.unapply)
}

case class PlayerGame(
  id: Long,
  createdAt: DateTime,
  lastModificationDate: DateTime,
  playerId: Long,
  level: Int,
  status: String
)

class PlayerGameTable(tag: Tag)  extends Table[PlayerGame](tag, "player_games") {
  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def createdAt = column[DateTime]("createdAt")
  def lastModificationDate = column[DateTime]("lastModificationDate")
  def playerId = column[Long]("playerId")
  def level = column[Int]("level")
  def status = column[String]("status")
  override def * : ProvenShape[PlayerGame] = (
  id,
  createdAt,
  lastModificationDate,
  playerId,
  level,
  status
  ) <> (PlayerGame.tupled, PlayerGame.unapply)
}
```

I want to write a query like this with Slick, where the `WHERE CLAUSE` is dynamic. I wrote two examples

```
SELECT *
FROM players
LEFT JOIN player_games AS playerGamesOne ON players.id = playerGamesOne.playerId AND playerGamesOne.level = 1
LEFT JOIN player_games AS playerGamesTwo ON players.id = playerGamesTwo.playerId AND playerGamesTwo.level = 2
WHERE playerGamesOne.status LIKE 'gameOver'
OR playerGamesTWO.status LIKE 'gameOver'


SELECT *
FROM players
LEFT JOIN player_games AS playerGamesOne ON players.id = playerGamesOne.playerId AND playerGamesOne.level = 1
LEFT JOIN player_games AS playerGamesTwo ON players.id = playerGamesTwo.playerId AND playerGamesTwo.level = 2
WHERE playerGamesOne.status LIKE 'playing'
OR playerGamesTwo.status NOT LIKE 'gameOver'
```

I was trying something like this, but I get `Rep[Option[PlayerGameTable]]` as the parameter. Maybe there is a different way of doing something like this

```
val baseQuery = for {
  ((p, g1), g2) <- PlayerTable.playerQuery joinLeft 
    PlayerGameTable.playerGameQuery ON ((x, y) => x.id === y.playerId && y.level === 1) joinLeft
    PlayerGameTable.playerGameQuery ON ((x, y) => x._1.id === y.playerId && y.level === 2)
} yield (p, g1, g2)

private def filterPlayerGames(gameStatus: String, playerGamesOneOpt: Option[PlayerGameTable], playerGamesTwoOpt: Option[PlayerGameTable]) = {
  (gameStatus, playerGamesOneOpt, playerGamesOneOpt) match {
    case (gameStatus: String, Some(playerGamesOne: PlayerGameTable), Some(playerGamesOne: PlayerGameTable)) if gameStatus == "gameOver"  => playerGamesOne.status === "gameOver" || playerGamesTwo.status === "gameOver"
 }
}
```

It is a complex question, if soemthing is not clear please let me know and I will try to clarify it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues:

1. With multiple conditions, the `underscore` placeholder used within your `ON` clause would not work the way intended
2. `_.level = something` is an assignment, not a condition

Assuming `PlayerTable.playerQuery` is `TableQuery[PlayerTable]` and `PlayerGameTable.playerGameQuery` is `TableQuery[PlayerGameTable]`, your `baseQuery` should look like this:

```
val baseQuery = for {
  ((p, g1), g2) <- PlayerTable.playerQuery joinLeft 
    PlayerGameTable.playerGameQuery on ((x, y) => x.id === y.playerId && y.level === 1) joinLeft
    PlayerGameTable.playerGameQuery on ((x, y) => x._1.id === y.playerId && y.level === 2)
} yield (p, g1, g2)
```

It's not entirely clear to me how your `filterPlayerGames` method is going to handle dynamic conditions.  Nor do I think any filtering wrapper method will be flexible enough to cover multiple conditions with arbitrary `and/or/negation` operators.  I would suggest that you use the `baseQuery` for the necessary `join`s and build filtering queries on top of it, similar to something like below:

```
val query1 = baseQuery.filter{ case (_, g1, g2) =>
  g1.filter(_.status === "gameOver").isDefined || g2.filter(_.status === "gameOver").isDefined
}

val query2 = baseQuery.filter{ case (_, g1, g2) =>
  g1.filter(_.status === "playing").isDefined || g2.filter(_.status =!= "gameOver").isDefined
}
```

Note that with the `left join`s, `g1` and `g2` are of Option type, thus `isDefined` is applied for the `or` operation.

On a separate note, given that your filtering conditions are only on `PlayerGameTable`, it would probably be more efficient to perform `filtering` before the `join`s.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I changed the query mistake I made and your answer it really makes sense to me. I am trying to get this working. I am not sure what mistake I am doing that, for example, in the `query1` the `===` can not get resolved.

Comment: I think the problem is the `joinLeft`, I am not sure, but I think that it is why I can not filter the conditions. Slick is not able to resolve `===` or `like`. I get `value === is not a member of slick.lifted.Rep[Option[Option[String]]]`

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I think that maybe the problem is that inside the `filter` I do not have a `Option[PlayerGame]` I have `Rep[Option[PlayerGame]]` maybe that's why the `===` is not being recognized, is that make sense to you?

Comment: @agusgambina, sorry I oversimplified the filtering queries.  Answer updated.

Comment: @agusgambina, just an FYI, the filtering queries have been simplified/refactored.